# How to determine count of distinct values of a field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called INFODOCS which has a field called PROCESSOR_ID and STATUS(True/False/Null).
I want to determine two things

1. Working_Processor = Count of Distinct PROCESSOR_ID where STATUS in not Null
2. Total_Processor = Count of Distinct PROCESSOR_ID

INFODOCS

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",,
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "11",
    "STATUS" : "True"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "11",
    "STATUS" : ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "22",
    "STATUS" : "False"
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "PROCESSOR_ID" : "33",
    "STATUS" : ""
  }
]
```

Here expected answer is:
Working_Processor = 2 (_id:1 and _id:3)
Total_Processor = 3

I tried using $addToSet with $cond, but want to know if there is better way of achieving the same.

```
[
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': None, 
            'WORKING_PROCESSOR': {
                '$addToSet': {
                    '$cond': [
                        {
                            '$ne': [
                                '$STATUS', ''
                            ]
                        }, '$PROCESSOR_ID', None
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            'TOTAL_PROCESSOR': {
                '$addToSet': '$PROCESSOR_ID'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'WORKING_PROCESSOR': {
                '$subtract': [
                    {
                        '$size': '$WORKING_PROCESSOR'
                    }, 1
                ]
            }, 
            'TOTAL_PROCESSOR': {
                '$size': '$TOTAL_PROCESSOR'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$PROCESSOR_ID",
      WORKING_PROCESSOR: {$max: {$cond: [{$ne: ["$STATUS", ""]}, 1, 0]}}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      WORKING_PROCESSOR: {$sum: "$WORKING_PROCESSOR"},
      TOTAL_PROCESSOR: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IGhBnsij6sW)

Comment: This code does not count distinct PROCESSOR_ID while determining WORKING_PROCESSOR. For example in the INFODOCS collection, if you set STATUS = 'True' for _id=2, WORKING_PROCESSOR should still be 2. Whereas the query returns 3.

Comment: You are right. The answer is updated accordingly.